# Display something after X number of form submissions from the same IP address in given amount of time

Tags: php, security, drupal-7, ip, recaptcha

I am looking for some advice.  I received a security requirement on our signup form (Drupal 7 site), to have reCAPTCHA displayed at the bottom of the page when there has been an X number of form submissions from the same IP address in a given amount of time.

I'm thinking I may need to grab the user's IP address via

```
  $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

assign it a timestamp, and store these in a database and run a loop for each check.

If there is a better way to do this or if anyone can offer any best practices, that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

create a table with`id, ip, mod_date`

then query it every time the page is loaded with

```
Select count(*) Where mod_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

that should give you a count

if the count is greater then whatever you decide: load the recaptcha

that should do it